# Setting item counter on smartdiagramanimated [circular diagram] using Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, smartdiagram

It is needed setting item counter on smartdiagramanimated [circular diagram] using Beamer. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}%Paquetes para organigramas
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\tikzset{% -- Codigo añadido para contador
   smvisible on/.style={smalt=<+->{}{sminvisible}},
}%

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramanimated}{r[] m}{%
   \StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% true-no value 1
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}}
   {%false-no value 1
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{}{%
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}
   }{}
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{circular diagram}{% true-circular diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{180+360/\maxsmitem*\xi}
   }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\maxsmitem*\xi}
   }
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
      \node[module,
        drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi)
       at (-\angle:\sm@core@circulardistance) {\smitem};
   }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
      \node[module,
        drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi)
       at (\angle:\sm@core@circulardistance) {\smitem};
   }
   }%
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnum\xi=\maxsmitem
     \ifcircularfinalarrowdisabled
       \relax
     \else
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\adv}{\xi + 1)}
       \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
       \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
         \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
          (module\xj) to[bend right] (module\xi);
         }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
          \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
           (module\xj) to[bend left] (module\xi);
         }
     \fi
   \else
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\adv}{\xi + 1)}
     \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
     \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
       \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
         (module\xj) to[bend right] (module\xi);
     }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
        \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
          smvisible on=<\adv->]
         (module\xj) to[bend left] (module\xi);
       }

   \fi
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-circular diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{flow diagram}{% true-flow diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0+\xi*\sm@core@modulexsep}
        in node[module,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at +(\n2,0) {\smitem};
   }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0-\xi*\sm@core@moduleysep}
        in node[module,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at +(0,\n2) {\smitem};
   }
   }%

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \ifnum\xi<\maxsmitem
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{smart diagram arrow back}
   \draw[diagram arrow type,smvisible on=<\xi->]
     (module\xj) -- (module\xi);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \fi
   % last arrow - not display it in background - check if disabled
   \ifbackarrowdisabled
     \relax
   \else
     \ifnum\xi=\maxsmitem
       \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
         \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
           to path={-- ++(0,\sm@core@backarrowdistance) -| (\tikztotarget)}
           }
         }
         \draw[diagram arrow type, square arrow,smvisible on=<\xi->]
          (module\xj.north) to (module\xi.north);
       }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
         \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
           to path={-- ++(\sm@core@backarrowdistance,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}
           }
         }
         \draw[diagram arrow type,square arrow,smvisible on=<\xi->]
           (module\xj.east) to (module\xi);
       }
     \fi
   \fi
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-flow diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{descriptive diagram}{% true-descriptive diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}

   \foreach \subitem [count=\xii] in \smitem{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\subitemvisible{\xi}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{1}{% true
   \node<+->[description title,drop shadow]
   (module-title\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
   }{}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{2}{% true
   \node<+->[description,drop shadow]
   (module\xi)at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
   }{}
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-descriptive diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{bubble diagram}{% true-bubble diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[bubble center node, smvisible on=<\xi->](center bubble){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[bubble node, smvisible on=<\xi->](module\xi)
        at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem };
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-bubble diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{constellation diagram}{% true-const diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[planet, smvisible on=<\xi->](planet){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[satellite, smvisible on=<\xi->] (satellite\xi)
    at (\angle:\sm@core@distanceplanetsatellite) {\smitem };
   \draw[connection planet satellite, smvisible on=<\xi->]
    (planet) -- (satellite\xi);
 }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-constellation diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{connected constellation diagram}{% true-conn const diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[planet,smvisible on=<\xi->](planet){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[satellite,smvisible on=<\xi->] (satellite\xj)
    at (\angle:\sm@core@distanceplanetsatellite) {\smitem };
   }%
   }%
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\xi}{1}{ %true
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
      \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xk}{mod(\xj,\actualnumitem) +1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\smvisible}{\xi+1}
      \path[connection planet satellite,-,smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
       (satellite\xj) edge[bend right] (satellite\xk);
   }{}
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-connected constellation diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{priority descriptive diagram}{% true-priority descriptive diagram
   \pgfmathparse{subtract(\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth,\sm@core@priorityarrowheadextend)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\sm@core@priorityticksize{\pgfmathresult/2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\arrowtickxshift{(\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth-\sm@core@priorityticksize)/2}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\smvisible{\xi+1}
   \node[description,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\smvisible->},smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
    (module\xi) at (0,0+\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\smitem};
\draw[line width=\sm@core@prioritytick,\col,smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
 ([xshift=-\arrowtickxshift pt]module\xi.base west)--
 ($([xshift=-\arrowtickxshift pt]module\xi.base west)-(\sm@core@priorityticksize pt,0)$);
   }%
   \coordinate (A) at (module1);
   \coordinate (B) at (module\maxsmitem);
   \CalcHeight(A,B){heightmodules}
   \pgfmathadd{\heightmodules}{\sm@core@priorityarrowheightadvance}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\distancemodules}{\pgfmathresult}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\arrowxshift{\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth/2}
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node[priority arrow] at ([xshift=-\arrowxshift pt]module1.south west){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-priority descriptive diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{sequence diagram}{% true-sequence diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \x[count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \ifnum\xi=1
     \node[sequence item,smvisible on=<\xi->] (sequence-item\xi) {\x};
   \else
     \node[sequence item,anchor=west,smvisible on=<\xi->]
      (sequence-item\xi) at (sequence-item\prevx.east) {\x};
   \fi
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-sequence diagram
   }% end-no value 1
}% end-command


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering
\begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
        \pause
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]     
        \item Es posible incrustar un gráfico de mapa de bits dentro 
            de un gráfico vectorial, pero no es posible incrustar información 
            vectorial en un mapa de bits.
        \item Las imágenes en los monitores de las computadoras también son 
            mapas de bits, al igual que las salidas de impresoras, escáneres y 
            dispositivos similares.
            \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
    \vspace*{-0.35cm}
    \begin{center}
        \scalebox{0.62}{\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
        font=\large,
        text width=2.5cm,
        module minimum width=2.5cm,
        module minimum height=1.5cm,
        arrow tip=to}
        \smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Configurar Paquetes,Editar Código,Analyse,Modify~/ Add,
        Check,Check again}}
    \end{center}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}   
    %\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Note that when item is 2, the circular diagram shows the graph, when it should be starting from item 4 and so on...

Comment: Your question is confusing. In the title you ask about `\smartdiagramanimated`, but in the code, you use non-animated version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}%Paquetes para organigramas
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\tikzset{% -- Codigo añadido para contador
   smvisible on/.style={smalt=<+->{}{sminvisible}},
}%

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramanimated}{r[] m}{%
   \StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% true-no value 1
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}}
   {%false-no value 1
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{}{%
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}
   }{}
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{circular diagram}{% true-circular diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{180+360/\maxsmitem*\xi}
   }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\maxsmitem*\xi}
   }
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
      \node[module,
        drop shadow={visible on=<.->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi)
       at (-\angle:\sm@core@circulardistance) {\smitem};
   }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
      \node[module,
        drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi)
       at (\angle:\sm@core@circulardistance) {\smitem};
   }
   }%
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnum\xi<\maxsmitem
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\adv}{\xi + 1)}
     \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
     \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
       \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        visible on=<+(-\maxsmitem+1)->]
         (module\xj) to[bend right] (module\xi);
     }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
        \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
          smvisible on=<+(-\maxsmitem+1)->]
         (module\xj) to[bend left] (module\xi);
       }
   \else
     \ifcircularfinalarrowdisabled
       \relax
     \else
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\adv}{\xi + 1)}
       \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
       \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
         \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        visible on=<+(-\maxsmitem+1)->]
          (module\xj) to[bend right] (module\xi);
         }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
          \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
           (module\xj) to[bend left] (module\xi);
         }
     \fi
   \fi
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-circular diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{flow diagram}{% true-flow diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0+\xi*\sm@core@modulexsep}
        in node[module,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at +(\n2,0) {\smitem};
   }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0-\xi*\sm@core@moduleysep}
        in node[module,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at +(0,\n2) {\smitem};
   }
   }%

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \ifnum\xi<\maxsmitem
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{smart diagram arrow back}
   \draw[diagram arrow type,smvisible on=<\xi->]
     (module\xj) -- (module\xi);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \fi
   % last arrow - not display it in background - check if disabled
   \ifbackarrowdisabled
     \relax
   \else
     \ifnum\xi=\maxsmitem
       \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
         \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
           to path={-- ++(0,\sm@core@backarrowdistance) -| (\tikztotarget)}
           }
         }
         \draw[diagram arrow type, square arrow,smvisible on=<\xi->]
          (module\xj.north) to (module\xi.north);
       }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
         \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
           to path={-- ++(\sm@core@backarrowdistance,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}
           }
         }
         \draw[diagram arrow type,square arrow,smvisible on=<\xi->]
           (module\xj.east) to (module\xi);
       }
     \fi
   \fi
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-flow diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{descriptive diagram}{% true-descriptive diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}

   \foreach \subitem [count=\xii] in \smitem{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\subitemvisible{\xi}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{1}{% true
   \node<+->[description title,drop shadow]
   (module-title\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
   }{}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{2}{% true
   \node<+->[description,drop shadow]
   (module\xi)at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
   }{}
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-descriptive diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{bubble diagram}{% true-bubble diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[bubble center node, smvisible on=<\xi->](center bubble){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[bubble node, smvisible on=<\xi->](module\xi)
        at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem };
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-bubble diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{constellation diagram}{% true-const diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[planet, smvisible on=<\xi->](planet){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[satellite, smvisible on=<\xi->] (satellite\xi)
    at (\angle:\sm@core@distanceplanetsatellite) {\smitem };
   \draw[connection planet satellite, smvisible on=<\xi->]
    (planet) -- (satellite\xi);
 }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-constellation diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{connected constellation diagram}{% true-conn const diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[planet,smvisible on=<\xi->](planet){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[satellite,smvisible on=<\xi->] (satellite\xj)
    at (\angle:\sm@core@distanceplanetsatellite) {\smitem };
   }%
   }%
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\xi}{1}{ %true
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
      \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xk}{mod(\xj,\actualnumitem) +1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\smvisible}{\xi+1}
      \path[connection planet satellite,-,smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
       (satellite\xj) edge[bend right] (satellite\xk);
   }{}
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-connected constellation diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{priority descriptive diagram}{% true-priority descriptive diagram
   \pgfmathparse{subtract(\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth,\sm@core@priorityarrowheadextend)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\sm@core@priorityticksize{\pgfmathresult/2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\arrowtickxshift{(\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth-\sm@core@priorityticksize)/2}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\smvisible{\xi+1}
   \node[description,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\smvisible->},smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
    (module\xi) at (0,0+\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\smitem};
\draw[line width=\sm@core@prioritytick,\col,smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
 ([xshift=-\arrowtickxshift pt]module\xi.base west)--
 ($([xshift=-\arrowtickxshift pt]module\xi.base west)-(\sm@core@priorityticksize pt,0)$);
   }%
   \coordinate (A) at (module1);
   \coordinate (B) at (module\maxsmitem);
   \CalcHeight(A,B){heightmodules}
   \pgfmathadd{\heightmodules}{\sm@core@priorityarrowheightadvance}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\distancemodules}{\pgfmathresult}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\arrowxshift{\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth/2}
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node[priority arrow] at ([xshift=-\arrowxshift pt]module1.south west){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-priority descriptive diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{sequence diagram}{% true-sequence diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \x[count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \ifnum\xi=1
     \node[sequence item,smvisible on=<\xi->] (sequence-item\xi) {\x};
   \else
     \node[sequence item,anchor=west,smvisible on=<\xi->]
      (sequence-item\xi) at (sequence-item\prevx.east) {\x};
   \fi
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-sequence diagram
   }% end-no value 1
}% end-command


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering
\begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
        \pause
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]     
        \item Es posible incrustar un gráfico de mapa de bits dentro 
            de un gráfico vectorial, pero no es posible incrustar información 
            vectorial en un mapa de bits.
        \item Las imágenes en los monitores de las computadoras también son 
            mapas de bits, al igual que las salidas de impresoras, escáneres y 
            dispositivos similares.
            \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
    \vspace*{-0.35cm}
    \begin{center}
        \scalebox{0.62}{\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
        font=\large,
        text width=2.5cm,
        module minimum width=2.5cm,
        module minimum height=1.5cm,
        arrow tip=to}
        \smartdiagramanimated[circular diagram:clockwise]{Configurar Paquetes,Editar Código,Analyse,Modify~/ Add,
        Check,Check again}}
    \end{center}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}   
    %\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]